# Can't connect to AWS instance from Bitnami AMI

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, bitnami

I'm trying to ssh from Ubuntu and use Putty\Filezilla from Windows to connect to my EC2 instance created from an AMI from the AWS Marketplace, but I always get the following error (I've tried root, ec2_user, bitnami and ubuntu as usernames):

```
OpenSSH_6.7p1 Ubuntu-5ubuntu1.3, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014 
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config 
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for * 
debug1: Connecting to 54.232.231.17 [54.232.231.17] port 22. 
debug1: Connection established. 
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory 
debug1: identity file madcloset.pem type -1 
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory 
debug1: identity file madcloset.pem-cert type -1 
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0 
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.7p1 Ubuntu-5ubuntu1.3 
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2 
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000 
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent 
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received 
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr umac-64-etm@openssh.com none 
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr umac-64-etm@openssh.com none 
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT 
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY 
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA 16:9f:ca:89:b8:68:cb:0c:ed:94:82:e0:77:4b:6e:ae 
debug1: Host '54.232.231.17' is known and matches the ECDSA host key. 
debug1: Found key in /home/juliano/.ssh/known_hosts:5 
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent 
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS 
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received 
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server 
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent 
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received 
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey 
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey 
debug1: Offering RSA public key: julianonunes@live.com 
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey 
debug1: Trying private key: madcloset.pem 
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey 
debug1: No more authentication methods to try. 
Permission denied (publickey).
```

I have created a new Key Pair and used Puttygen on Windows, but still the same error.

Why?

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should consider asking this on http://superuser.com/ instead. Or just search for "Permission denied (publickey)" and see all the other questions on the same subject.

Answer (score 0):

Bitnami developer here,

To connect to your Bitnami based Amazon Web Services instance you have to use `bitnami` as the username and use the private SSH key that you selected or generated when launched your server using the Amazon EC2 Control Panel. Please note that you will need to specify the SSH key using option `-i` for the SSH command. For example, the SSH command would look like:

> ssh -i /path/to/your/ssh_key bitnami@your_ec2_instance_dns_name

You will need to specify the SSH key because the `bitnami` user does not have a password by default and also because we have disabled using passwords for SSH connections. You can enable it once connected if you prefer.

Also, note that once logged in, you can use the `sudo` utility to become the root user if necessary by running command `sudo su`.

Hope it helps,

Gonzalo